# Реферальная ссылка Telegram Bot, Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Необходимо приглашать друзей к боту по реф ссылкам, и при этом Пользователю который пригласил, давать бонусы. 
Дайте наводку, как можно организовать этот процесс.
Обязательно ли создавать БД?

Comment: `Обязательно ли создавать БД?` А какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: @gil9red Значит заносить ID пользователя в базу? Получается что основная работа идет с БД?

Comment: Ну да, без базы данных выйдет фигня. Можно сначала с sqlite3 попробовать

Comment: @gil9red, Хорошо, получается после генерации ссылки, надо как-то получать реф ссылку человека который перешел по ссылке?

Comment: Получается так. http://t.me/BotFather?start=123q124, есть такая ссылка, пусть  "123q124" это сгенерированный реферальный номер, его надо как-то получить. Ведь при переходе по этой ссылке в телеге или в других местах, на направляет к боту, где мы должны нажать кнопку "Start". Так вот значение что после "=" должно передаться. Как его получить?

Comment: Не знаю, погуглите API телеграмма, на вопрос передачи боту параметров при его запуске

Answer (score 3):

Решил проблему гениально! http://t.me/BotFather?start=123q124, переходя по этой ссылке нас кидает в к боту, если мы её открываем в телеге, либо на веб-странице, которая потом редиректит в телегу. После того как мы появились у бота, нажимаем на кнопку "Start", В этот момент в боте выводим наши данные после "=" обычным `message.text[7:]` Возможно это дурацкий способ, но он рабочий.

Comment: Объясните, а в чем магия `message.text[7:]`?

Comment: @gil9red, мне необходимо было сделать рефферальную ссылку, как я и говорил ранее, Чтобы бот передал какие-то значения после нажатия кнопки старт, необходимо добавить после `?start` "=" и после него значение указать. Дело в том, что необходимо было сравнивать это значение вытягивая значение с БД, с помощью `print(message.text)` мы получаем ответ такого вида: '/start значение_после_знака_равно'. И сравниванием с тем значением что в БД. `message.text. отображает вводимый пользователем текст боту.

Comment: Понятно, т.е. те 7 символов, что пропускаем это `?start=`, а дальше уже идет идентификатор, который и нужен был

Comment: Там отображается /start 123q124, то есть выводим весь текст после "/start "

Comment: @DavidGederim `message.split()[1]`

Comment: про deep linking почитайте