# Как создать и обработать реферальную ссылку с помощью python aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Как мне сгенерировать реферальную ссылку на телеграмм бота с помощью aiogram?
Как поймать реферальную ссылку и узнать из нее id с помощью aiogram?
Что нужно дописать в этот хэндлер для обработки ссылки ?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"], state="*")
async def user_registration(message: Message):
    await message.answer(text="Выберите свою роль.", reply_markup=choise_role)
    await RegistrationStates.choice_of_role.set()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/836342/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-telegram-bot-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все достаточно просто)

```
def extract_unique_code(text):
    # Extracts the unique_code from the sent /start command.
    return text.split()[1] if len(text.split()) > 1 else None

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"], state="*")
async def user_registration(message: Message):
    #Выделение id рефера
    unique_code = extract_unique_code(message.text)
    if unique_code:
        #если есть id рефера
        pass
    else:
        #если в ссылке нет id рефера
        pass
    await message.answer(text="Выберите свою роль.", reply_markup=choise_role)
    await RegistrationStates.choice_of_role.set()
```